# Get item from QListWidget using a QItemSelection or QModelIndex

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a callback in my dialog to listen for item selections in my QListWidget:

```
...
QListWidget* listWidget;
...

MyDialog::handleSelectionChanged(const QItemSelection& selection) {
    if (selection.indexes().isEmpty()) {
        std::cout << "NOTHING SELECTED" << std::endl;
        // TODO: how to get the actual QListWidgetItem here!?
    }
    else {
       bool selected = LoadedFilesListWidget->selectionModel()->isSelected(selection.indexes().first());
       std::cout << "ITEM CHANGE: " << (selected ? "SELECTED" : "UNSELECTED") << std::endl;
       // TODO: how to get the actual QListWidgetItem here!?
    }
}
```

As you can see in the todos, I can't figure out how to get the associated QListWidgetItem from the QItemSelection object.  I have access to the list widget with the `listWidget` class variable.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to obtain a `QListWidgetItem` from the selection, you can do the following:

```
MyDialog::handleSelectionChanged(const QItemSelection& selection)
{
    [..]

    QModelIndexList indexes = selection.indexes();
    foreach(const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
        QListWidgetItem *item = LoadedFilesListWidget->item(index.row());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!